# Brakes or front tie rods

Tags: brakes, noise

I have a 2003 Nissan Altima SE 3.5v.

I had my tie rods replaced with new ones and the same sound they made when they went bad is back again. I noticed that the boot had come loose and I had to reattach it and add more grease. This worked for a couple days. Now, every time I brake it makes a horrible clicking and grinding noise like it did when my tie rods were bad, and a knocking squealing that is always there when I use my brakes in Drive. Using the brakes in Reverse does not make any of those sounds.

Also, my idler pulley is so loud, that at times it drives me crazy. It gets quieter sometimes, but it's always clicking. What exactly do I need to replace it?

Comment: Thank you and the only thing it doesn't click any noises turning either way only using the brakes I basically try to not even.touch them to stop I slow way back if.I know im.going to have to stop.

Answer (score 3):

Grinding when braking is usually low brake pads; I'm surprised, however, that the garage that did the tie rods didn't advise on new pads (and maybe rotors if you're hearing really bad noises).

If you've had to add grease to 'something' in that area with a boot on, it's likely the CV joint. That could make clicking and clunking sounds (but not a grinding sound). If it's gone, the quickest/cheapest/easiest solution is to replace the entire driveshaft on that side. The best test for a worn CV joint is to drive in tight circles, left and right, in a car park, and listen for the noise. The damaged side is the one on the opposite to your turn (so if you're turning right, and hear the noise, it's the left-hand CV joint that's gone)

If you're hearing noise from an idler pulley (not related to the brake noise, of course), then you're looking at, at a minimum, replacing the idler pulley.

Best recommendation is to take the car to a brake specialist; Tell them about the symptoms, and don't put solutions in their mouths. See what they recommend; if two or more shops recommend the same fix, go with the one you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: Per OP: "Thank you and the only thing it doesn't click any noises turning either way only using the brakes I basically try to not even.touch them to stop I slow way back if.I know im.going to have to stop."

Comment: *may* not be the CV joints then - but my advice to take it to a brake shop still stands.